MySQL workbench UI issue
I have two different macbook. I am still using MacOS 10.15.6 on my older laptop with MySQL Workbench 8.0.15. I can easily create tables from the d.
On my another laptop I am on MacOS 14.4.1. The workbench (8.0.36) does not allow me to create tables. Not sure if this a workbench issue or the OS issue.
Has anyone else faced this issue?
How do I resolve this issue?
Workbench 8.0.15
enter image description here
Workbench (8.0.36)
enter image description here
I tried downgrading the mysql workbench version to 8.0.15, still facing the same issue.
